# 'Who got it right?' '3 people got it right'

Tags: words, syntax, questions

みなさん、こんばんは！

I was just wondering how you would say the phrase or phrases:
"Who got it right?" or "who is correct/right"
"'Tom got it right" or "3 people got it right"

To give some extra context, some Japanese language students and I have started meeting up to play games in Japanese. At the moment, we're playing 'Dixit' (super fun game in a group). At the end of every round, one of the players from the group has to determine who got the correct answer. It would be nice to be able to ask the question and respond accordingly.

Here are the attempts we came up with in our group:
"だれが正しいですか" "だれが当たりましたか" 
"三人は正しいです" "Tomは当たりました"

Thanks in advance for any answers. Also, I would definetely recommend playing Dixit if you've never tried :).

よろしくお願いします！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way of asking a group of people a yes or no question about something directly related to them is using the pattern:

〜した人？

When I hear this, I immediately jump to an image of a teacher asking a group of students a yes/no question in class and they all raising their hands while saying "はい".

For example,

今日の給食が美味しかった人？
Who liked today's (provided) lunch?

This is not really used in formal situations or written Japanese, however since you say you're looking for a way to determine verbally who got the correct answer in a group, I feel this is your best option.

In other words, you could say:

はい、正解した人？
or
はい、当たった人？
or even
はい、正しい答えをした人？

(the はい is just a way to grab people's attention if they're talking or whatnot)

When answering this kind of question, a show of hands is the usual/expected outcome.

If the scorekeeper wanted to then announce to the group who got it right (which if you're playing face-to-face should be immediately obvious from the show of hands, but I've admittedly never played Dixit before), they could say something like:

今回の正解者は3人いました/Tomだけでした。

or

今回3人が/Tomだけ(が)当たりました。

Comment: note this 〜した人？ type of question doesn't HAVE to be in the past tense if you're not asking about the past. 正解が分かる人？would mean, for example, "who knows the right answer?".

Comment: Thank you Sbkgs! I appreciate your thorough answer. Just a question about the pronunciation. Does the '人 ' have the 'hito' pronunciation?

Also, the scorekeeper is the one who decides who got the correct answer, the other players don't know they're right until the scorekeeper decides (it's a game based on interpretation). How would the players be able to ask to the scorekeeper 'who got it right?' ?. Based on your examples would it be something like this:

誰が正解しましたか
or
誰が当たりましたか

As in 'Who got it right? because we don't know and you are the one who decides'.

よろしくお願いします！

Comment: @Kaney Dudey I apologize for not including ふりがな! You are correct, though, the pronunciation is ひと. As for the second part of your question, if I'm understanding the situation correctly your translations would work just fine! It seems like that's what you were asking from the beginning, so sorry for having answered the wrong question! 笑